# How do I alter the title display with hook_user_view?

Tags: users

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view().
 */
function my_statistics_user_view($account) {
    $account->content['statistics']['daily_avg'] = array(
        '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
        '#title' => t('Daily average'),
        '#markup' => 'Hello',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('daily-avg')),
    );
}
```

The above code renders:

```
Daily average
Hello
```

in a user's account profile. I would like to render it inline, like this:

```
Daily average: Hello
```

How is this done? Thanks.

Comment: There is function called hook_user_view_alter
use this one
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. To alter display, you have to create or edit [`user-profile.tpl.php`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7) file in your theme, or [template_preprocess_user_profile()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7) function in `template.php`

Comment: The solution I choose was to alter user-profile-item.tpl.php. It seems that adding an #attributes element to the array does not add a class to the dt and dd elements (that wrap the title and value). This would be a more targeted approach. If anyone can make it work, please add your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could either theme the form label inline (e.g with CSS), or include the label as part of the markup, for example something like:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_user_view().
 */
function my_statistics_user_view($account) {

  $value = 'Hello'; // for example
  $account->content['statistics']['daily_avg'] = array(
    '#type' => 'user_profile_item',
    '#title' => t('Daily average'),
    '#title_display' => 'invisible',
    '#markup' => t('Daily average: @value', array('@value' => $value)),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('daily-avg')),
  );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest way here is just to use [drupal_set_title](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_title/7):

```
function my_statistics_user_view($account) {
    drupal_set_title('Your desired title here');
}
```

Comment: Arr wait, he doesn't actually want to edit the title - I should read the question properly before answering!